# Objective-C fetch doesn't always return a result

Tags: objective-c, core-data, uimanageddocument

I have the following code:

```
-(void) readAllQuestions {
    NSLog(@"Reading questions from database");

    NSManagedObjectContext* moc = self.questionsDocument.managedObjectContext;
    moc.mergePolicy = NSRollbackMergePolicy;

    NSFetchRequest* request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"QuestionEntity"];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"modified" ascending:YES];
    request.sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray* results = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    NSLog(@"Read %d question entities", [results count]);
    self.questionsArray = results;
}
```

questionsDocument is a UIManagedDocument

My problem is, that this code doesn't always return the entities. Well in fact it actually never does it the first time I call it. When I call it the second time it works and also when I debug.

So I think there is an asyn problem going on.

Who can help me?

initializer:

```
-(id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        [self openDocumentIfItExistsOrCreateNew];
        [self readAllQuestions];
    }
    return self;
}
```

code to open document:

```
-(void) openDocumentIfItExistsOrCreateNew {
    QuestionsDocument* document = [self createDocument];

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:document.fileURL.path]) {
        [self addDocument:document];
    }
    [document openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
        if (success == NO) {
            [NSException
             raise:NSGenericException
             format:@"Could not open the file %@ at %@",
             FILE_NAME,
             document.fileURL];
        }
    }];

    self.questionsDocument = document;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`openWithCompletionHandler` works *asynchronously*, which means that it only initiates opening the document in the background. The completion handler block is called later, when the document actually has been opened.

So you cannot call `[self readAllQuestions]` directly after `[self openDocumentIfItExistsOrCreateNew]`. You could for example move that into the completion handler block:

```
[document openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
    if (success) {
         [self readAllQuestions];
         ... update UI (reload table view or whatever you have) ...
    } else {
          // report error
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

That code

```
NSArray* results = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if (error) {
```

is not correct.

Make that

```
if (results == nil) {
    NSLog (@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
```

Comment: Thanks, I am using your solution now!